# Conditional ActionLink in Razor view not rendering(asp.net mvc 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am scratching my head as to why not this isn't working:

```
@if (Model.Guid != null) { Html.ActionLink("Fil", "GetFile", new { id = Model.DocumentID }); }
```

The conditional on its own is working as putting som random HTML in there instead of an actionlink works:

```
@if (Model.Guid != null){<span>Test</span>}
```

Likewise the actionlink on it's own renders without a problem.

Could anybody clue me in to what is going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put an @ sign before the Html.ActionLink.

Like this:

```
@if (Model.Guid != null) { @Html.ActionLink("Fil", "GetFile", new { id = Model.DocumentID }); }
```

EDIT: Forgot to add that you don't need the semi colon, but you can leave it in if you want.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I was already in code and didn't need the @.

Comment: I thought of the same thing @user109657